# Error Occured While Recording the User Voice In IOS APP

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, noise

I am developing an Voice App .I am using Nuance Speech kit for voice Processing .What i am doing is ,i am reading the text and play it in voice .and then recording user voice for the input....So while recording i am getting the Error like .

**NMT CloudRecognizer Error [Session ID:035141cf-4d5e-45ba-b81a-e8121b657cd8] [Type:2] [Code:5] [Message:(null)] [ErrorParam:AUDIO_INFO] [Prompt:Sorry, speech not recognized. Please try again.]
2017-06-20 03:56:10.171307 Link[573:131453] CloudRecognizer Error [Session ID:035141cf-4d5e-45ba-b81a-e8121b657cd8] [Type:2] [Code:5] [Message:(null)] [ErrorParam:AUDIO_INFO] [Prompt:Sorry, speech not recognized. Please try again.]**

I want know to why this error message is occurring .if it included the background noise means.How can i reduce or remove the background noise while recording ..Please help me to do this. I want to remove the background noise while recording the User voice.

Thanks in 
Advance!!!

Comment: Share recorded audio

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev ,where can i share the audio file. can you please tell you email id

Comment: Upload to dropbox and give here a link

Comment: 1-NUAN-48dc480d-3d44-4605-9856-2f6a91b76e8b-SESSION-b54994c7-9fc4-4f2d-8683-1b9d7c0569fc-audio_2.wspx8.wav
                                                                                                                      2-NUAN-06aca9de-b6b2-4c98-b59f-87b646e7618b-SESSION-46cf0f6a-898c-4cbe-a5eb-729a7317057b-audio_2.wspx8.wav

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ugjzsfaokimn96/NUAN-48dc480d-3d44-4605-9856-2f6a91b76e8b-SESSION-b54994c7-9fc4-4f2d-8683-1b9d7c0569fc-audio_2.wspx8%20%281%29.wav?dl=0

Comment: I shared a dropbox link here .Please look at this